# Dojo - click method and selectors

Tags: dojo

How can I rewrite the script below, written in jQuery, in Dojo?

```
$('table > tbody > tr').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dojo.query('table > tbody > tr').forEach(function(node) {
    dojo.connect(
        node, 
        'onclick', 
        function() { 
            alert('clicked');
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks but already solved in such way: dojo.query('tbody > tr').connect("onclick", function(){
        alert(123);
    });

Comment: In this simple example that works fine, but you can't get the node which was clicked like that. I was assuming you'd need that at some point :)

Comment: Of course you can get the node that was clicked even with Chvanikoff's solution. The `onclick` function receives the event object, and the event object has the `currentTarget` property for precisely this purpose.